# How to stop popup-alert propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not know how to explain this in English;-) 
**If I choose an option alert displays for every choice I do not know how to stop.**

Step 1, choose "aaaa" option eg 
1111 alert ...

Step 2, choose option "bbbb" for example 
1111 alert ... 
2222 alert ...

and so on!

I've tried return, stopPropagation, etc.. 
It will surely be an easy mistake to correct for you ... :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-  1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myList').on('click', 'li', function(e) 
        {
            var pos = $(this).attr('pos');
            $("#myPopup").popup('open');

            $('#myPopup').on('click', 'ul li a', function(ev)
            {
                var popupValue = $(this).attr('info');
                alert('option-->' + popupValue);
                $('#myPopup').popup('close');
            }); 
        });     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">


<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">

<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Choose an option...</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
  <ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:250px;">
    <li><a href="#" info="1111">aaaaaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" info="2222">bbbbbbb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" info="3333">cccccc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time you click the list you bind a new copy of the popup click events. Bind the events once at the start instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-  1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myList').on('click', 'li', function(e) 
        {
            var pos = $(this).attr('pos');
            $("#myPopup").popup('open');

            $('#myPopup').off().on('click', 'ul li a', function(ev)
            {
                var popupValue = $(this).attr('info');
                alert('option-->' + popupValue);
                $('#myPopup').popup('close');
            }); 
        });     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">


<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">

<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Choose an option...</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
  <ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:250px;">
    <li><a href="#" info="1111">aaaaaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" info="2222">bbbbbbb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" info="3333">cccccc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: explain what you did ?